# How can I queue and execute multiple promises asynchronously with a single callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, promise

I am using the http request library [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got). With this package, http connections are asynchronous, fast, and easy to type out. The "`got`"cha is that `got` is a promisified package, which brings up several challenges for me. One is that I don't know how to pass around a reference to the `got`.

What I need to do is use `got` together with file streams to download the page contents of several url's. Upon completion of **all** of these streams, I want to continue in the code.

In this example instead of making an array of promises I am getting an array of response objects.

```
const getFile = (fileUrl) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    got.stream(fileUrl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.basename(fileUrl)))
    .on('finish', () => {
      successMessage('downloaded ' + fileUrl + '!');
      resolve();
    });
  });
};

// create an array of these got promises
let promises = []
for (let file of body.files) {
  promises.push(getFile(file));
}
```

The reason the `getFile` helper exists is to wrap the `got` in a promise so that after performing all of the `got`s, I can use a `promise.all` call:

```
// after all got's have executed
promises.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log('all promises resolved');
}
```

Looking for assistance understanding how to change the first snippet so that `promises.all` behaves as anticipated.

Comment: It's `Promise.all(promises)`, but other than that your code should work. What's the error?

Comment: I think you just spotted the bug Bergi. I'd post that answer before someone comes and steals your well earned internet points!

Comment: @Bergi you should post that as a full response, it worked for me and you deserve the correct answer for this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Promise aggregation function is called `Promise.all()` not `promises.all()`.